# Can I send CefSharp LoadRequest without Frame Rendering

Tags: c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

Can we make LoadRequest call which does not render frame just like a typical XHR or Fetch request for the purpose of getting some remote json and submit it on already/previously loaded main frame form?

I tried LoadRequest with X-Requested-With and CORS headers but no luck.

Comment: You can inject JavaScript function(s) to make an XHR.  If you want c# to get the result instead you can do whatever the CefSharp version of CefURLRequest is - https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/GeneralUsage#markdown-header-browser-independent-requests